# Changing notifications from standard to custom type

Tags: android, notifications, custom-controls

Changing from a standard `notification` with text and a picture to more complex types with custom designed layout requires the use of RemoteViews class.  And instead of using the setContentTitle(), I used setContent(remoteviews) method because of the custom view.

After changing to custom view I deleted the `setContent, setSmallIcon,` and `setContentTitle mehods`,  however after I did that the notification never showed up again.

If I am using a custom view all I have to use us the setContent() method is that correct?  they why does it not work with I remove the other methods?

```
RemoteViews remoteviews = new RemoteViews("com.test.example", R.layout.custom_notifications);

 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AudioService.this)
           .setContent(remoteviews)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!")
            .setOngoing(true);
```

Comment: Well you still need to set a ticker text and an icon to show up in the status bar when the notification is sent unless you have set the priority of the notification to the lowest priority just like Google now's weather notification.

Comment: so in that case I guess these methods are needed regardless of if the notification is custom or not

Comment: Yes, you always need `icon` and `contentView` set on a notification or it will be ignored. The latter is produced either with the `Builder` or the deprecated `setLatestEventInfo()` and constructor, or by creating your own `RemoteViews` as you've discovered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well since ICS I have not really touched the Notification Builder. Even to this day I still do it the old school way when GB was more popular. Example time:

```
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

            // Setup an intent for when the user taps the notification
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

            // `icona` is the icon shown in the status bar. 
        Notification notification = new Notification(icona,
            "Ticker Text", System.currentTimeMillis());

            // These flags should be self explanatory 
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

            // This is where you select the xml for you custm view
        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.custom_notification);

        notification.contentView   = contentView;
        notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

            // Some ID number for the OS to keep track of your notification     
        int HELLO_ID = 123456;

            // Send the notification
        mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
```

This should work for every release of android. Simply because `Notification.Builder` is a wrapper to make it easier to create status bar notifications. Also the builder calls these methods if you look at androids source code.

Comment: FWIW, `NotificationCompat.Builder` (in the support-v4 library) does all this for you using the newer `Builder` API but it also works on older versions of Android.